# image and icon resize for google play console

Tags: image, google-play, icons

I want to upload an image to google play store and I resized the picture like you do other picture with this step: Tools => Adjust size => and Image Dimensions meeting the requirement of google play store. However, I got this error message:

```
You need to resize your high-res icon. The required dimensions are 512 x 512
```

and for the feature graphic:

```
You need to resize your feature graphic. The required dimensions are 1024 w x 500 h.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like you haven't resized your icons properly. But without more details of your images and what OS you are on, it is hard to help more.

If you are on Linux then [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/275502/how-to-get-information-about-an-image-picture-from-the-linux-command-line) tells you how to display the sizes:

- For PNG `file foo.png`
- For JPG `identify -format "%wx%h" photo.jpg` where identity comes from the ImageMagick program

If you are on windows there [are detailed instructions here](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/guides/KnowledgeBase/5616-determine-an-image-s-file-size-and-dimensions). Essentially highlight the file in explorer

Whichever of the above you do, please either take a screenshot of the result (for Windows) or the text output (for linux) and edit your question to include it, then people can check you have resized properly.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that art. It's Mac